# adapter for listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to display data in listview from my database (like latitude and longitude) along with data based on a sensor listener and location listener (direction and distance, not residing in database). Direction and distance will change as user moves. Items will be sorted by distance. I have implemented content provider for getting data from database so far.
I have issues with designing adapter and/or loader. Should I use custom cursor adapter or it's better to extend ArrayAdapter and fill data from cursor? Also should I use CursorLoader or implement custom one?

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading from database simplest would be using `SimpleCursorAdapter`. The idea is you set up which table field names correspond to which xml views. You, probably, don't need Content Provider unless you want to export your data to outside apps. There are lots of examples of how to use `SimpleCursorAdapter`. I guess you will want to override `onBindView` to populate the list because some data are not from db.